# Phalcon moveTo function is not moving files to target directory in server?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading, phalcon

I'm trying to upload an image to a specific directory but the function `moveTo` is not moving the image.

```
public function uploadRecipeImageAction() {
    if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true) {
        $file = $this->request->getUploadedFiles()[0];
        $target_file = '/uploads/ketogenic-recipes/'.preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\_\-\.]/i", '', basename($file->getName()));
        $file->moveTo($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $target_file);
    }
    return $target_file;
}
```

The function works fine locally but it's not working in server. There are no errors in logs

`uploads` and `ketogenic-recipes` directory permissions are set to `0775`

PHP Version **7.2.20**

Phalcon version is **3.4**

```
var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) = string(30) "/home/web/public_html/test2"
var_dump($target_file); = string(42) "/uploads/ketogenic-recipes/harrypotter.jpg"
```

Comment: `/uploads/ketogenic-recipes/harrypotter.jpg` is an absolute path? You are aware it is outside the project (sorry for asking)?

Comment: @Tpojka actually it is `web/ uploads/ketogenic-recipes/filename` but web is skipped via htaccess. And even I tried by adding web. But still not working.

Comment: `$target_file` is pointing exactly at an absolute path related to OS root location. 
You need to combine `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` when you are setting `$target_file` location. Probably `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/ketogenic-recipes/'.preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\_\-\.]/i", '', basename($file->getName()));` or something similar. You have to set file location related to your web server, not related to system root and `'/what/ever/comes/after/initial/slash'` should be an absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We moved from old server to new server. And I found few wrong configurations which was the reason for not moving images/files to target directories.

### PHP-FPM was not enabled

Our site was running on PHP `7.2.20` but `PHP-FPM` was not enabled on our website. So this means it was not using site specific `php.ini`

### Wrong home directory

I mistakenly set home path for the sub-domains in cPanel. They were pointing to the sub-domain root instead of the `web` folder ( *in phalcon we have web as home directory* ). So `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` was pointing to the root folder; not to the `web` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the problem was directly linked to the PHP `upload_max_filesize` set to 2MB by default. Increasing the value in `php.ini` file fixed the problem.